# Installing solid tires without locking pins?

Tags: tire

Finally I decided to buy solid tires. At the moment I placed the order I did not know that they are installed with locking pins. Is it required to have locking pins or I can just pull the tire onto a rim?

[image: Solid 700c tires]

Comment: There are several brands. Which brand? Anyway you need to do it properly or risk your tyre coming off the rim when you least want it to

Comment: Follow the manufacturer's directions.

Comment: @ChrisH Here is product I ordered http://s.aliexpress.com/Bvq2mIbU in comments they say no pins included and if I understood correctly, no pins needed

Comment: Wow, looking at that .... I think you're a brave person for trying those. Please do post photos of 'before' while the tires are still on and 'after' photos from the ER when the tires have rolled off your rim while you were cornering.

Comment: Usually we think that a screwdriver might damage rims, and here the instructions recommend a crowbar...

Comment: I think this buyer's comment sums it up nicely    "EVERYTHING well, although the FOOTPRINT, perfect endings or aesthetic don't a PNEUMATIC DETAILS, to start to roll not noticeable. the aid days PNEUMATIC You will BE a poco deformed, poco to poco You will tomar shape, very nice, colorful and difficult to assemble... patience. Very fast Dispatch!! recommend and Is the second Is to buy!"   (literal quote)

Comment: @vladdihoney whatever happens, please document it well and post your own  answer here showing how it worked for you.  Whether you needed hot water to soften the tyre, or soapy water to get it on the rim.  Also some comments on how it rides would be great.   The last "solid" tyre I had was in the mid 80s.

Comment: @Criggie If I survive on those tires, of course!

Comment: I love some of the reviews for this product. For example: "The figment Is Good, But Bike change comportment, is ago More slow and heavy.". or "the seller is good but the product is really crappy same for train... the bike stands very locked... recommend not!", or "The rubber spends very fast. should not last long.". ...all of which don't surprise me. One user recommended glue to keep the thing in place.

Comment: @vladdihoney Did you survive your new tyres?  How did they work for you?  I remember riding  "no-more-flats" in the late 80s until they perished with age.    Do add your own answer showing how it worked, and feel free to mark it as accepted.

Comment: @Criggie I had an accident in autumn, broke my front wheel and fork so “no more fixies for now”

Comment: @ojs I think crowbar is a translation error.  I've recently seen it applied to plastic tyre levers

Comment: Im still trying to find where to buy these pins. Looks like there is Tannus website and cycletogo.com that sells them. As for the size, im a bit confused as to which one to buy. Im running a 700 x 23.

Answer (score 2):

**No** - because the solid tire can be put onto a rim, but the only problem is that they come off as soon as you brake for a corner.

Sites like aliexpress.com and Amazon all sell those solid bike tires without the t-bolts to attach it to the wheel rim.

So don't buy them without the plastic t-bolts!

Answer (score 1):

A seller of airless tires in 2013 demonstrates how to install his product onto a (spokeless) rim, pushing it in place, using a zip tie cinched tight to hold it for starters as he progressively levers the tire over the rim flange with a large, plastic prying spatula, finally kneading it all round, inch by inch, to seat the tyre.

This writer suggests it may go easier if the tire is warmed up. Cursing may do the trick.