# where to buy the locking pins called t-bolts for installing solid airless bike tires?

Tags: mountain-bike, tire, wheels, rims

The solid airless bike tires come with predrilled holes to insert locking pins [t-bolts] so the tire will stick to the rim of the wheel.
Good quality manufactures sell their tires with these plastic locking pins.
But even amazon does not.  So i need to find the manufacturer?

Comment: What are the good quality solid tire manufacturers?

Comment: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/49725/installing-solid-tires-without-locking-pins

Comment: Tannus sell pins for their solid tyres, which may or may not work with other brands